# C#. Считать значение, используюя класс Interlocked

Tags: c#, многопоточность, строки, указатели

Необходимо реализовать доступ (изменение/считывание) из потоков к общей переменной с помощью класса Interlocked.
Фрагменты кода:
Общая переменная:

```
string bufferMessage = "None";
```

Запись в переменную:

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref bufferMessage,
                     "Thread #" + threadName + " WRITE message: " + i);
```

Считывание:

```
messagesRead.Add("Thread #" + threadName + " READ message: "
                  + Interlocked.Read(ref bufferMessage));
```

Запись проходит успешно, считывание компилятор не хочет пропускать. Выводит ошибку:

```
Не удается преобразовать из "ref string" в "ref long"
```

Есть вообще возможность считывания значения строковой переменной с помощью класса Interlocked?

Comment: `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref bufferMessage, null, null)`

Answer (score 2):

Метод [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.interlocked.read(v=vs.110).aspx) предназначен исключительно для чтения 64-битных чисел(*long*) на 32-битных системах, так как чтение 64-битного числа на них не является атомарной операцией. 
Поэтому как для типа *string*, так и для других типов *double*, *float* и тд в классе Interlocked явной функции чтения не существует.

Спасибо @PetSerAl, как он заметил верно, можно атомарно прочитать значение с помощью метода [CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb297966(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref bufferMessage, null, null)
```

Данный метод будет всегда возвращать значение текущей переменной bufferMessage, так как `bufferMessage != null`(идет сравнение переменной bufferMessage c 3 аргументом функции)